# Android Widget - (Kotlin) Disable "Refresh" Button while loading (not refreshing twice or more often)

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, broadcast

I've got an Android (News) Widget with a list of Elements and a Header.
Within this header, I've got a refresh button. If the user clicks the button the list gets updated.
The widget works fine. Refresh works and everything seems to be OK.
However, I've got one problem: If the user clicks on the refresh button multiple times the request gets sent multiple times as well. And that even while loading is still in progress.
I need to prevent any re-load while it is still loading. The problem seems that preventing within the `onReceive` method is too late.
Is there any possibility to hide/disable/... the refresh button while the app is still loading -> Important: Before sending the broadcast intent.

This is my code:

```
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(
    R.id.image_reload,
    context.pendingBrodcastIntent<NewstickerListAppWidgetProvider>(
        appWidgetId,
        NewstickerListAppWidgetProvider.ACTION_UPDATE_LIST
    )
)
```

I can hear the click sound if I click the refresh button.
I know it is possible because there is a different app, where it works as I would like it to work:
With the "DER SPIEGEL," you can hear the click sound only while the app is not refreshing. This means they block the sending broadcast pending intent with some mechanism: They are able to hide the refresh button after clicking it once, so a double tap is prevented.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Call `setViewEnabled` method just before the `setOnClickPendingIntent` solved my problem:

```
views.setViewEnabled(R.id.image_reload, canRefresh)
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(
    R.id.image_reload,
    context.pendingBrodcastIntent<NewstickerListAppWidgetProvider>(
        appWidgetId,
        NewstickerListAppWidgetProvider.ACTION_UPDATE_LIST
    )
)
```

I call the method `updateAppWidgetList` (where the code above lives in) twice.
First time with `canRefresh` set to false and one second later with `canRefresh` set to true.
This prevents clicking the refresh button twice within a second.